# How to use Entity Class with our Model Class in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all I want to ask that what is the difference between Entity Class and our Model Class ?

And when I use to add Data Annotations on the Entity Classes generated by the Entity Framework in Database approach, it's vanished upon every "Update From Database", and for this user defined Model Classes can be used but I have no idea to use them with the generated Entity Classes.

Answer (score 0):

An entity class is a class that directly associate's with a real object and is linked to business logic and holding information about the system. Entities are usually used to establish a mapping between an object and to a table in the database.

Models are simply classes that are associated with a views and controllers which define or contains the definition of an object and when there has been a change in state. These can hold your data annotations to validate before going up to the Business/Data Access layers...

This leads me on to your next question and if using EF to generate your data model classes using the "database first" approach, then you cannot apply the data annotation attributes directly to your classes. Because the EF Designer generates the model classes, any changes you make to the model classes will get overwritten as you have been experiencing. If you want to use the validators with the classes generated by EF then you need to create meta data classes: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/01/20/adding-metadata-to-entities-in-the-data-model.aspx

Hope that helps.

Danny